# .0 Decimals In CSS Data Attributes

Tags: css, custom-data-attribute

hoping for some help with the following.

The code needs to hide items depending on the variable entered. For example below is between 4 and 4.9. So the top 2 lines of this code combine perfectly to achieve this, however if the number 4 is entered as 4.0 it applies the variables for decimal numbers.

This is my attempt to have the decimals (.1 - .9) do one thing will have whole number (4) and (4.0) do another.

At the moment lines 2 and 3 of the code conflict and neither works. Any help on how to fix this or a better way to write this code would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
[data-customer-rating="4"].review-card__stars .review-card__stars__star-o:nth-of-type(n+8) {display: none:}
[data-customer-rating="4."].review-card__stars .review-card__stars__star-o:nth-of-type(n+9) {display: none:}
[data-customer-rating="4.0"].review-card__stars .review-card__stars__star-o:nth-of-type(n+8) {display: none:}
.review-card__stars .review-card__stars__star-half-empty {display: none;}
[data-customer-rating*="."].review-card__stars .review-card__stars__star-half-empty {display: flex;}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)?

Comment: Please add the HTML it is impossible to assertain how CSS should work or why it doesn't work, or whatever. Also, you mentioned variables so I'm assuming you have JavaScript? If so post it along with the HTML and CSS as a [mcve].